# How to create a collection of multiple types and use them with their type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 custom types, `Graphic` and `Asset` and I want to have them in the same array. I want to be able to access them and have access to their type information.

```js
const trail: Array<Graphic | Asset> = [];

for (let index = 0; index < this.props.graphics.length; index++) {
    const graphic = this.props.graphics[index];

    trail.push(graphic);

    if (index <= this.assets.length - 1) trail.push(this.assets[index]);
}

// this doesn't work, .artist does not exist on type Graphic | Asset
if (typeof trail[0].artist != "undefined") {

}
```

I'd image the following type of approach could work, but I haven't found a way to.

```js
enum TrailType {
   Graphic,
   Asset
}
interface Trail {
   type: TrailType
   element: Graphic | Asset
}
```

Is it only possible to do this when the types share at least one property?

Comment: If there is a property (such as artist) in one of the types, checking if  `'artist' in trail[0]` should do what you want.

Comment: You can help Typescript by using `in`,  eg.  `if ('artist' in graphic) { /*type for artist here*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to have some kind of way to define what the type is. It is called a `discrimanted union`. You can read about it here [https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/understanding-discriminated-unions-in-typescript-1ccc0e053cf5#:~:text=The%20discriminant%20is%20a%20singleton,the%20discriminant%20or%20the%20tag](https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/understanding-discriminated-unions-in-typescript-1ccc0e053cf5#:%7E:text=The%20discriminant%20is%20a%20singleton,the%20discriminant%20or%20the%20tag).

In your case, it will look in the following way.

```
interface GraphicTrail {
    type: TrailType.Graphic,
    element: Graphic
}

interface AssetTrail {
    type: TrailType.Asset,
    element: Asset
}

type Trail = GraphicTrail | AssetTrail
```

Now you can do `if` check to verify with which type you are working, and thus Typescript will be able to narrow down the type of the variable.

The other solution is `type guard`. For instance.

```
function isGraphic(data: Graphic | Asset): data is Graphic {
    return Boolean(data.someFieldsThatExistsOnGraphicOnly); // Here any boolean expression that you fill confident with will work.
}
```

Comment: The first Approach worked for me, the second one still gave me an error saying that the property doesn't exist. Too bad that functions cannot return the right type for the first approach, therefore need to use if statements everywhere.